# How to debug an application which suddenly terminates without any feedback?

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

The application uses Xamarin.Android, which may be a big problem in itself. The problem is that sometimes it *just quits* (process is being terminated) and there's nothing in the log that can be associated with it. (although I guess that it's related to running out of memory, but I can't yet prove it — according to DDMS, most of the times all is OK, and if Xamarin.Android uses another pool of memory, then I don't know how to measure it)
I've searched the code base for "Environment.Exit" and, of course, didn't found anything.
What are the options for finding the culprit of such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the garbage collector by yourself. Just run

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

The Runtime instance has also a method to read the free memory space. So you could figure out by yourself whether it's a memory problem.

EDIT:
Oh I read that Xamarin uses the C# language. But I'm quite sure that C# has similar methods.

Comment: C# has similar method for running GC and if I remember right, for read free memory space too
I will try doing it, thanks for the idea

Comment: Great. I hope you'll figure out the problem. Unfortunately I'm not fit with Xamarin. I just had a memory problem with a fragment which displays a few more images. I solved it with calling the garbage collector on deleting the fragment by myself.

Comment: Seems like it crashes much less often when forcing GC each 5 seconds, which is strange and it makes me think that monodroid GC is broken

Answer (score 0):

When you say log, are you referring to an application log, or the device log?

When tracking down these sorts of bugs, I've always found [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) invaluable.

I open it, clear all the current logs, then use my application up to the point where it crashes. Then I quickly go back to aLogCat, pause it and scroll up to where the error is - it's usually found in the nearest red/orange blocks.

There's a blog post [here](http://spiritmachineblog.tumblr.com/post/52943080201/creating-a-link-description-for-xamarin-android-and) about how I found attributes left out by the Xamarin linker using this method.

Comment: "Application log" includes messages from "LogCat", and I checked both of them.